# Neo4j OGM not saving RelationshipEntity

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have read every single question on SO but I still can't figure out why OGM for Neo4j doesn't save my RelationshipEntities.
Here PubmedDocumentNode and PubmedAuthorNode are both saved, but not the relationships citations and authors. MeshHeadingsUI edges instead are created fine.

Code:

```
@NodeEntity
public class PubmedDocumentNode extends Node {
    @Id
    @Index(unique = true)
    public int PMID;
    ...

    @Relationship(type = "CITES")
    public List<PubmedCitesRelationship> citations;
    @Relationship(type = "MeSHClass")
    public List<MeSHClass> MeshHeadingsUI;
    @Relationship(type = "AUTHOR")
    public List<PubmedDocAuthorRelationship> authors;

    public PubmedDocumentNode() {
        node_type = NODE_TYPE;
        citations = new ArrayList<>();
        MeshHeadingsUI = new ArrayList<>();
        authors = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

@NodeEntity
public class PubmedAuthorNode extends Node {
    ...

    @Id
    @Index(unique = true)
    public String Author_Name;
    ....
}


@RelationshipEntity(type = "AUTHOR")
public class PubmedDocAuthorRelationship extends FeatureEdge {

    public PubmedDocAuthorRelationship() {
        label = new float[]{3.0f}; //just to try
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public long Id;

    @StartNode
    public PubmedDocumentNode document;
    @EndNode
    public PubmedAuthorNode author;
}
```

Parent classes:

```
public abstract class FeatureEdge extends DistributedNeo4jEntity {
    @Property
    public float label[];

    public FeatureEdge() {
    }
}

public abstract class Node extends DistributedNeo4jEntity {
    ...
    public float state[];
    public float label[];
    ...

    public Node() {
        ...
    }
}

public abstract class DistributedNeo4jEntity extends Neo4jEntity {

    ...
}

public abstract class Neo4jEntity {
    @Labels
    public List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>(); //I already tried to comment this but no luck
}
```

Save code:

```
    //s is obtained by openSession
    Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
    arts.forEach(x -> s.save(x));
    //arts.forEach(x -> x.authors.forEach(y -> s.save(y))); //tried also
    //arts.forEach(x -> x.citations.forEach(y -> s.save(y)));  //tried also
    tx.commit();
    tx.close();
```

Comment: What version of OGM are you using? There was a restriction in 3.0 that `RelationshipEntities` have to have at least one additional property to get persisted.

Comment: They do have. See labels[] in FeatureEdge.

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed the inheritance here. Could you please tell me what version of OGM you are using?

Comment: Both neo4j and OGM latest version, just downloaded. OGM in my pom is v. 3.1.0